# Detect click on background event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have a [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) calendar and I add on it some background events. Those background events represent slots that cannot be clicked or dragged into. Is there a way to detect this (that the user clicked on a background event)?

Comment: A background event is a regular event, just rendered different, if user clicks on background event you still can get the event properties via eventClick callback, with this you can start doing your validations.

Comment: @JuanCarlosV are you sure? I exected this was the case but I cannot get it to work - see [here](http://jsbin.com/gotuke/1/edit), the click on the background event does nothing.

Comment: That's correct Leo, I misunderstood the docs, one solution could be to use eventClick or dayClick callbacks to iterate through the events array and look for background events on that date clicked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Background event is rendered as a DIV with the class name fc-bgevent.

My code for detecting the click background event is:

```
element.fullCalendar({ 
    ...
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
            alert('Click Background Event Area');
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this does not solve a problem that exists when there is more than one background event on the same row.  If there is, only the last background event on that row will be detected.  I have started a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426002/how-to-detect-a-click-on-a-background-event-when-two-or-more-background-events-a)

Comment: I'm using fullcalendar 2.7 with scheduler plugin and jsEvent.target.classList only contains "fc-highlight", do you know how to fix your code to make it work with this fullcalendar version?

Comment: This is not working at all. The target is always `fc-highlight`

Comment: @LingasamySakthivel It works for me when I changed following class z-index on fullcalandar.css .fc-time-grid .fc-highlight-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

Comment: Just one thing: at @fullcalendar/core@^5.6.0 the event is called fc-bg-event.