# Detect background events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using FullCalendar in my project. I used background events, `rendering="background"`. How can I detect if user click on the background events? I try this but it doesnot work since all dates cannot be clicked.

```
dayClick: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view,color,calEvent) {
            if (calevent.rendering==="background") {
                alert('Click Background Event Area');
            }
            else{
            $('#modal1').modal('show');
           }

            if (start.isBefore(moment())) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/ - "eventClick will not be triggered for background events." And I don't know where you got that method signature from for dayClick - it doesn't resemble either of the ones in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/dayClick/

Comment: doyou have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can check on this link. It has answered your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359369/detect-click-on-background-event

Answer (score 4):

Since fullCalendar doesn't expose an "click" type event on background events, the only way I can think of to do this is essentially a DIY approach. The basic idea:

- Handle the "select" event
- Fetch all the events currently in fullCalenar's memory, using the "clientEvents" method.
- Loop through them all and check whether any of them are background events, and if so, whether they overlap with the selected time period. If they do, then that's the event that was clicked on.

I haven't tested this, but it's based on some old code I found, so hopefully you get the idea:

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var cal = $("#calendar"); //put the ID of your calendar element here
    var evts = cal.fullCalendar('clientEvents'); //get all in-memory events
    var selectedEvent = null;

    for (i in evts) {
        if (evts[i].rendering == "background" && start.isBefore(evts[i].end) && end.isAfter(evts[i].start)) {
            selectedEvent = evts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The only flaw in this is that "select" allows selection of a time period, not just a single click, so it could be that the selection is *overlapping* the background event, and not wholly contained within it. You might be able to adjust the logic a little bit if that doesn't suit you - e.g. to require that both start and end are within the event's boundaries.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks for your idea

Comment: @hud. did you have any luck with this?

Comment: doesn't work how exactly? You get an error, or it doesn't meet your requirements in some way? If you can be more specific, maybe we can get something that is better.

Comment: There is no error. But the day cannot be clicked. It seems like select function are not functioning