# Detect Background Event FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I used background events, rendering="background". I try to catch background event click. So i try this :

```
dayClick: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#New').modal('show');
},

selectOverlap: function (calEvent) {
    if (calEvent.rendering === 'background') { 
        $('#Request').modal('show'); 
    }
},
```

When I clicked the day, it opened `Request modal` and `New modal`. I only want `Request modal` to be opened.

Comment: dayClick doesn't record a click on a particular event, just the whole day. Maybe using eventClick would be better? Then you can check the status of the event. Perhaps if you could be clearer about your actual intention it would be easier to say. Should the "New" modal open in some other circumstance?

Comment: "New" modal should be opened whenever the user clicked any date. while "Request" modal will be opened only if the user clicked at background events. So I cant check if the event is background or not since the dayClick doesn't record the event click.

Comment: In that case move your call to the New modal from "dayClick" to "select", since that's the intended place for creating new events, as far as I understand it. DayClick isn't very good for this, because, as you point out, it doesn't know whether you clicked an existing event or not.

Comment: Can capture background event in `select` function?

Comment: Ok, a quick google search shows that I answered this kind of thing once before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477878/detect-background-events - see if my answer there helps you. You haven't said _why_ you want to "capture" a background event, but in that link, the purpose is to stop the user from creating new events on top of background events. If that's your purpose too, then it will help. If not, then please be clearer about what you want.

Comment: for (i in evts) {
                    if (evts[i].rendering === "background") {
                        $('#PatientList').modal('show');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#OnlineRequest').modal('show');

                    }...so i use like this but it opened both modals

Comment: ok so now we have a new one, PatientList, instead of New...the plot thickens. So when you say "both", which of the 3 possibilities do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved like that:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
  if(jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-highlight'))
  {// code for backgroud event
  }
  else
  { //code for empty slot click 
  }
},
```