# How to check non-selectable slots on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a different range of available hours for every single day, for example:

- monday 4th from 9:00 to 14:00
- monday 4th from 16:00 to 18:00
- thursday 5th from 9:30 to 15:00
- wednesday 6th from 10:00 to 12:00
- wednesday 6th from 16:00 to 18:00
- ...
- monday 11th from 12:00 to 14:00
- monday 11th from 15:00 to 17:30
- ...

These ranges can change from a day to another. They're stored on a database and I render them on the calendar using the "rendering: background" property.

The user can only create events on these ranges. When the user clicks inside a "rendering: background" range they can see a modal window that prompts the user for creating a new event.

My problem is: when I click on the calendar outside a "rendering: background" slot -let's say on monday 4th at 14:30h- the modal window is shown. How can I avoid this? When the user clicks outside a non-permitted slot I want they to show an error message, not the modal window.

This is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        height: 1055,
        //aspectRatio: 0.5,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
        columnHeader: false,
        columnFormat: 'Class type',
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        weekends: false,
        selectable: true,
        eventRender: my_render_function,
        },
        select: function (start, end, jsEvent) {  // click on empty time slot
        // code to show my modal for creating a new event
        ...
        ...
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
        selectOverlap: function (event) {
            // Here you will get all background events which are on same time.
            return event.rendering === 'background';
        },
        businessHours: {
            // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
            dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Thursday
            start: '09:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
            end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
        },
        minTime: '09:00:00',
        maxTime: '18:00:00',
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/agenda/my_existent_events'
                }
            },
            {
                url: '/agenda/mybackground_events_with_colors'
            }
        ],
    })
```

I've tested this solution but it doesn't work for me:
[Detect click on background event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359369/detect-click-on-background-event)
Any suggestion will be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectAllow`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectAllow/) option.

It Provides you with Exact programmatic control over where the user can select.

```
function(selectInfo)
```

This callback will be called for every new potential selection as the user is dragging.

The callback function will receive information about where the user is attempting to select (`selectInfo`) and must return either `true` or `false`.

The `selectInfo` object will have the following properties:

`start` (a [Moment](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/))

`end` exclusive end date/time (a Moment)

`resourceId` if you are using a [Resource View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scheduler/)

Additionally, you can look into the options available related to select [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/)

Hope that helps you out

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that Resource view is part of the premium plugin (I cannot use this). I use select option but I don't understand how to use this with selectInfo option, is there any example I could use?